# Random formula for choice winner

Tags: javascript, php, random, logic

i have site with promos and users, users can reg in promo, then 1 random user can win in this promo.

Now simple formula for choice winner:

```
$total_users = 100; //total users in promo
$winner_number = rand(1,$total_users);
```

But now user can invite anyone with unique link to promo and clicks on his link increase his invite counter for this promo:

```
$users[] = ['user_id'=>8,'invites'=>5];
$users[] = ['user_id'=>17,'invites'=>150];
$users[] = ['user_id'=>69,'invites'=>30];
$users[] = ['user_id'=>32,'invites'=>0];
... //array with users in promo
```

And need new formula to choice winner depends of invites (more invites - more chance to win), but without linear progression to win chance(avoid cheating)

The weighting should be like in this graph:

[image]

Comment: How does the number of invites affect the chances of winning if not linear?

Comment: Well... It's **your** promotion.  You need to decide how exactly you want to reward your users.

Comment: Java ? JS ?? nope

Comment: @JayDM need formula like this in image - https://yadi.sk/i/63H_G6pNGx6veg

Comment: Are you looking for a weighted random selection, where the weight is the number of people they've invited?

Comment: @azro any language, i need  understand only logic of this

Comment: @Barmar yes, but with cheat resistance, see image in previous my comment, pls

Comment: That graph looks like it's logarithmic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first off - it looks like the number of chances that each user gets would be something like:

chances = to_integer(1 + (bonus_rate * (1 - 1 / (slope_adjustment ^ invites))))

For example, if the bonus_rate was 10 and the slope_adjustment was 2 then:

- 0 invites would get you (1 + (10 * (1 - 1 / (2 ^ 0)))) = 1 chance
- 1 invite would get you (1 + (10 * (1 - 1 / (2 ^ 1)))) = 1 + 5 = 6 chances
- 10 invites would get you (1 + (10 * (1 - 1 / (2 ^ 10)))) = 1 + 9.99 = 10 chances
- 1 million invites would get you (1 + (10 * (1 - 1 / (2 ^ 1000000)))) = 1 + 9.999999 = 10

By adjusting the bonus_rate and slope_adjustment you can control the number of additional chances that each user gets.

Next - you need to plot that number of entries onto some space (an array, number line, etc) and randomly pick a point in that space to find your winner.

The simplest way would be to add one element to an array for each entry then just randomly pick one.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly the formula that I need!

I don’t know why people put me off, maybe it was obvious for everyone, but not for me, thanks for helping out.

Comment: No worries. I don't think that people were trying to give you trouble. They were just trying to get enough information to be able to answer you actual question. It can be very easy to answer the wrong answer when there is not enough information to narrow down the problem. And no one wants to waste their time. The better you are able to define your problem - the more likely folks will be willing to give their time to help you. :)